# How to solve the following polynomial recursion $p_n(x)= p_{n-1}(x)(x^2-a)+\left( \frac{b}{x}-2x \right) p_{n-1}'(x)+p_{n-1}''(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

How to find the solution to the following polynomial recursion
\begin{align}
p_n(x)= p_{n-1}(x)(x^2-a)+\left( \frac{b}{x}-2x \right) p_{n-1}'(x)+p_{n-1}''(x)
\end{align}
with $p_0(x)=1$ for some fixed constant $a$ and $b$.

The first two terms of this are given by
\begin{align}
p_1(x)&=x^2-a\\
p_2(x)&= x^4 - (2 a+4) x^2 + 2 b+a^2   + 2\\
p_3(x)&= x^6 +(2a+ 6b+ 3a^2+ 30)x^2  - (3a+12)x^4    - 8- 8b - 6ab - 6a- a^3
\end{align}

This question arose as part of another question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4602030/expression-for-left-fracd2dx2-fraccx-fracddx-rightk-p/4602551#4602551).

Comment: Shouldn't $p_1(x)=x^2-a$?

Comment: @user777777777 are correct. I wrote $p_0$ instead of $p_1$